# Change a matrix into lower triangular matrix

Tags: algorithms, matrices

I have a matrix over integer of size (50,50). I want to know whether it is possible to exchange rows and columns in such a
way so that the transformed matrix is a lower triangular whose diagonal entries are non zero.

Is there any algorithm which can determine this efficiently?

Comment: By only exchanging rows and columns this is not possible for all matrices. Do your matrices have a special form which allows you to do that? Or do you want to allow adding linear combinations of rows/columns also?

Comment: Yes, I want to know for my matrix it is possible or not. No I do not want  linear combinations.

Comment: Let $[50]=\{1,2,...,50\}$. Consider $R:[50]\to P([50])$ such that $R_k$ is the set of rows at which the column $k$ in your matrix is non-zero. You can find a solution by back-tracking in the following way. First you choose $k_1\in[50]$ such that $\{b_1\}=R_{k_1}$ consists of only one element. If there is no such $k_1$ there is no solution. Suppose that $k_1,k_2,...,k_{r}\in[50]$ have been chosen. Then choose $k_{r+1}\in[50]\setminus\{k_1,k_2,...,k_{r}\}$ such that $\{b_{r+1}\}=R_{k_{r+1}}\setminus(\bigcup_{t=1}^{r})R_{k_t}$ has exactly one element. If no such $k_{r+1}$ exist we backtrack.

Comment: Once we are able to choose $k_1,k_2,...,k_{50}$, then there is a solution and the permutations $(k_1,k_2,...,k_{50})$ and $(b_1,b_2,...,b_{50})$ tell you the permutations of rows and columns that you need to do.

Comment: If a particular row has $k$ zeroes on it, switching columns will not change $k$, and likewise for columns. So the basic qualification is that your source $n\times n$ matrix has a row and a column with at least $n{-}1$ zeroes, another row and column with $n{-}2$ zeroes, etc. Additionally for fulfilling the row/col cases of more than half zeroes, the row/column pairs meeting these requirements also need to meet in a zero (which will end up in the upper triangle).

Comment: Do you allow exchanging rows and columns independently? That is, if you exchange the first two rows, do you also have to exchange the first two columns?

Comment: Yes, we can exchange rows and columns independently